SMS opt-in requirements
So I work with a rewards platform that allows businesses to send their employees rewards.  We wanted to expand to sending these gifts to people via SMS but are trying to navigate the Opt-in requirements of TCPA.  We are not sending promotional messages.
Our messages would be transactional in nature and would be sending users a small message from their sender and a link to their reward.  Everywhere I go and explain our use-case, I'm told we are required to directly have opt-in.  Seems like our competitors are somehow getting around this, I wonder if it is just how I'm framing the use case.
